# DateTime.Parse returns wrong value when CultureInfo is used

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

This is my code:

```
DateTime Now = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-ir"));
```

The Geogorian date is: 16/06/2016

The Persian date is: 15/03/1395

while the value of Now is: 07/09/2025

The time is correct.
What can be the problem?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? Note that a `DateTime` value doesn't have an associated culture.

Comment: well I wanted to convert from geogorian date to persian

Comment: Then you should just use `DateTime.Now`, and get the year/month/day using the `PersianCalendar` class.

Comment: Well I used to use it that way but this is much more easier

Comment: Well it sounds like you don't want to so much convert as just format in that case. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to obtain the year, month and day of "now" in the Persian Calendar, you should use the `Calendar` class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var calendar = new PersianCalendar();
        Console.WriteLine($"Year: {calendar.GetYear(now)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Month: {calendar.GetMonth(now)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Day: {calendar.GetDayOfMonth(now)}");
    }
}
```

If you just want to format a value as a string, you can pass the `CultureInfo` into the `ToString` call:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo("fa-ir");
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(culture));
    }
}
```

Here, the `CultureInfo` has a default calendar associated with it (as well as date/time format strings) and that is used to format the value.

A `DateTime` itself is always effectively in the Gregorian calendar system - there's no way of creating a "`DateTime` in the Persian Calendar" for example, or "converting" a `DateTime` from one calendar to another.

Note that in my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, that's not true - you *can* specify a calendar system for a `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` value, and convert from one to another. If you're doing a lot of calendar work, I'd recommend you at least give Noda Time a try - it's designed to make it a lot harder to make this sort of mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You are only passing a cultureinfo param to Parse, but not to ToString. This means the string is formatted using the thread culture, and then parsed using fa-ir culture.

Comment: Well `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString() ).ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Settings.Language));` solved it but I'm curious the why pass the cultureinfo to parse? what is the use of it?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: The culture is associated with the right calendar, as well as the date/time formatting.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Note that there's no point in calling `DateTime.Parse` there - your code is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(...))`. Don't perform format/parse operations unless you actually need to.